# API Query must start with or match string, rather than being found anywhere in the string

Tags: api, search

https://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/api_series_characters.php?character_q=Rin

When querying 'Rin' it maxes out without actually getting to anyone named "Rin" (say, Rin Tohsaka who, if you search Rin+Tohsaka or Rin%20Tohsaka or just Tohsaka, is in this database).

I can put 'Rin20%' in to get anyone whose name is (x)rin (x) but it still maxes out in Ka***rin***s and such before getting to all Rins, and then if you want JUST 'Rin' (say from Catherine; also confirmed in database; ID 108203) you can't. %20rin%20 only gets us people whose middle name is Rin. Any ideas how to make it pull 'Rin's proper?

After getting the datachunk, I can force it to start with something and filter out the inappropriate matches (the P***rin***ces, the Ki***rin***os). But the API maxes out so I can't further filter it down. I need to get the API to deliver me Rins in the first place.

Comment: If you don't control the code of the API in question, there really isn't anything you can do, short of contacting the maintainers and letting them know they need to implement proper pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nick Bailey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620954/api-query-must-start-with-or-match-string-rather-than-being-found-anywhere-in-t/72749506#comment128280735_72620954) is correct:

> If you don't control the code of the API in question, there really isn't anything you can do, short of contacting the maintainers and letting them know they need to implement proper pagination.

One must contact the API controller if standard query keys are not handled as expected. (One should not expect a change in the API though, unless you are an exclusive or very major user; as others have likely worked with it as it currently operates).